# Is this BOM in UTF-8 incorrect?

Tags: c++, gcc, utf-8

I want to verify BOM in UTF-8, and wrote the c++ codes below.

However, the result was **0XFFFFFFEF, 0XFFFFFFBB, 0XFFFFFFBF**.

This is different from what I expected **0XEF, 0XBB, 0XBF**.

Why did the result became above?

By the way, the UTF-8 file used was made by Notepad++.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
        char file[]="/*UTF-8 file*/"; 
        
        char a[3]{};

        ifstream ifs(file, ios_base::binary);
        
        ifs.read(a, static_cast<streamsize>(sizeof(a)));
        
        cout << showbase << uppercase;
        
        for(int i:a){
                cout << hex << i << endl;
        }
}
```

## Environment

GCC 9.2.0

compile option：-std=c++2a

Comment: `for(int i:a){` over a `char` array? Hmmmm... *sign extension*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The BOM itself is fine. You are simply printing out the bytes incorrectly.

The result you are seeing is due to [**sign extending**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_extension) signed 8bit `char` values to signed 32bit integers. Whether `char` is *signed* or *unsigned* is compiler-defined, unless you state it explicitly in code. In your case, you are using (implicitly) signed `char`. Signed `char` values > 127 will have their high bit set to 1, which will fill in the new bits with 1s when extending a signed 8bit value to a signed 32bit value.

To output the bytes correctly, you need the values to be zero-extended, not sign-extended. Use `unsigned` types for that, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char file[] = "/*UTF-8 file*/";
    unsigned char a[3];

    ifstream ifs(file, ios_base::binary);
    ifs.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(a), sizeof(a));

    cout << showbase << uppercase;

    for(unsigned int i : a){
        cout << hex << setw(2) << setfill(‘0’) << i << endl;
    }
}
```